# What should land as an api?

Tags: api, design-patterns, architecture, api-design

This is a bit generic question .
Take the case as follows

There exists an web api ApiA .
now this does some task taskA.

Now we see that the customers are having a need to do another taskB which is closely related to taskA but not exactly taskA. so as to do this taskB there is no direct api at present. So customer decides to use apiA itself and do some actions(like making multiple say 2 ApiA calls)  and somehow achieve taskB . Now the customer has achieved taskB just with apiA itself .

So now from the point of view of company that provides these api's , is it fare to make a decision that just because taskB is a widely used task , they can now introduce a  separate apiB to do taskB itself directly. Or is it fare to make a decision that there shall not be apiB as this is already achievable with workarounds using apiA.

**Questions** :

1) Which do you think is the best design ?

2) can someone quote examples of how people have handles such situations in the past .

Specific answers with quoted examples might help .

Note : I know that the question might get mixed generic answers . Not sure if this question is apt to be here. If not let me know , I can post it somewhere else .

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, and experience, depending on what the API task actually DOES, it might be VERY reasonable for the company to implement an API::TaskB.  Otherwise, if you think about it, when people ask "How do I do "TaskB?"", the answer will always be a HACK.  "Well, you create an API Object, and then call TaskB Twice, it will do what you want...".. Well, to ME, that seems "Hacky", and, just incomplete.  So, at THAT point is IS reasonable to implement a TaskB that does what the user wants in a SINGLE call.  Does that make sense?  It not only makes the Company look good, because they have an API call for 'everything', or at least to do what the user expects you should be able to do...  If the task is not very useful, and provides like, some hacky results, and only a handful of the people USING the API will EVER use it, then-- Well, you don't NEED to really add the second API call, TaskB.

Sorry, I'm not quoting EXACT instances, I don't have any handy, but I have seen this type of stuff in the field before.  My answer is based strictly on what my years of programming, and Quality Assurance has taught me.

Answer (score 0):

That is where Object Oriented Programming comes in handy. You would create method TaskB() within the same class that has TaskA. You can then call TaskA() from within TaskB() to implement whatever functionality you need done. Look into Design Patterns for the best way to do what you want. I would recommend reading about the "Command Design Pattern".

Comment: I am not asking about the implementation . I am just asking if introducing apiB makes sense here ...